# Why do complex elements of $R(x)$ cancel?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers

**Edit of original post:**

I've been noodling around with non-trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function, and in particular with the expression

$$\sum_{\rho}R(x^\rho)$$

where $R(x)$ is Riemann's famous approximation to the prime counting function, and $\rho=\sigma+it$ represents all instances of non-trivial zeroes of the zeta function.

Since the non-trivial zeroes come in conjugate pairs, this expression can be expanded to

$$\sum_{\rho}\bigl(R(x^{\sigma+it})+R(x^{\sigma-it})\bigr)$$

Henrik has explained (comments below) why the complex components cancel.

This means that the sum $R(x^{\sigma+it}) + R(x^{\sigma - it})$ must equal $2$ times some real value. How do I arrive at this real value?

**Original post, for the record:**

I've been noodling around with non-trivial zeroes of the Riemann zeta function, and in particular with the expression

$$\sum_{\rho}R(x^\rho)$$

where $R(x)$ is Riemann's famous approximation to the prime counting function, and $\rho=\sigma+it$ represents all instances of non-trivial zeroes of the zeta function.

Since the non-trivial zeroes come in conjugate pairs, this expression can be expanded to

$$\sum_{\rho}\bigl(R(x^{\sigma+it})+R(x^{\sigma-it})\bigr)$$

What I can't figure out is why the imaginary components of $\bigl(R(x^{\sigma+it})+R(x^{\sigma-it})\bigr)$ cancel.

I know that the complex exponent of a real base is given by

$$x^{\sigma+it}=x^\sigma \biggl(\cos \bigl(t \ln(x)\bigr)+i\sin \bigl(t \ln(x)\bigr) \biggr)$$

and I tried plugging this into the equation

$$R(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^k}{kk!\zeta(k+1)}$$

but then I got tangled up in summing powers of logarithms, and didn't get anywhere.

Could someone help me understand why the complex components cancel?

Comment: Is $x$ suppose to be real and nonnegative? In that case this would follow from the fact that $R$ is meromorphic (so that $R(\bar z) = \overline{R(z)}$) and from $x^{\sigma- \operatorname{i} t} = \overline{x^{\sigma+ \operatorname{i} t}}$.

Comment: $x$ is indeed real and non-negative. And that is the perfect answer. How do I mark it as such?

Comment: Please find the answer below.

Comment: OK, noted. But can I ask a supplementary question first? I'll add this to the OP. If the complex components of $R(x)$ cancel (as they do), then summing $R(x)$ and $R$ for the conjugate of $x$ (which I don't know how to write in MathJax) presumably leads to an expression of $2$ times some value... How do I find that value?

Comment: That should be 2 twice the sum of the real part of the summands as $z + \bar z = \Re(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Probably $2 \sum_\varrho R(x^\sigma)$. But a simpler expression for that is out of my reach. I'm not a specialist in analytic number theory. =)

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesn't work (I tried). I have no idea why...

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"?

Comment: I mean that if I remove the complex component from $R(x)$ and double the result (using Mathematica), I end up with a different result from if I add together $R(x)$ and $R(y)$ where $y$ is the conjugate of $x$. (Sorry, don't know how to create the sign for conjugate in MathJax...)

Comment: So, this question _is_ Mathematica-related in the end? Then please provide the code that you use for $R$. (Btw. you can use `\bar{z}` and `\overline{z}` to typeset  conplex conjugation - `\overline{}` is extendable; `\bar{}` is not.)

Comment: Sure: `Evaluate[{RiemannR[x^(1/2 + E I)] + RiemannR[x^(1/2 - E I)], 
    RiemannR[x^(1/2) (Cos[E Log[x]] + I Sin[E Log[x]])] + 
     RiemannR[x^(1/2) (Cos[-E Log[x]] + I Sin[-E Log[x]])], 
    RiemannR[x^(1/2) (Cos[E Log[x]])] + 
     RiemannR[x^(1/2) (Cos[-E Log[x]])]} /. 
   x -> {1/2, 1/E, 1/\[Pi], E, \[Pi]}] // N`

Comment: Ah I see that I was wrong. You won't get further in simplification as `RiemannR[x^(\[Sigma] + I t)] + RiemannR[x^(\[Sigma] - I t)] == 
 2 Re[RiemannR[x^(\[Sigma] + I t)]]` for real, nonnegative `x`: Aslo try `\[Sigma] = 1/2;
t = E;
Evaluate[{RiemannR[x^(\[Sigma] + I t)] + RiemannR[x^(\[Sigma] - I t)],
     2 Re[RiemannR[x^(\[Sigma] + I t)]]} /. 
   x -> {1/2, 1/E, 1/\[Pi], E, \[Pi]}] // N // Chop`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'll mark this and your first answer as 'answered' if you do that clever conversion thing again!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning a comment into an answer.*

Is $x$ suppose to be real and nonnegative? In that case this would follow from the fact that $R$ is meromorphic (so that $R(\bar z)= \overline{R(z)}$) and from $x^{\sigma−\operatorname{i}t} = \overline{x^{\sigma+\operatorname{i}t}}$.